# Passenger/Nginx error "unexpected end of file detected."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I'm trying to run my applications under Passenger 3.0.2 on Mac OSX 10.6.4 with Rails 2.3.8 and 3.0.4. Using Ruby EE v2011.01. And Nginx.

I have completed this successfully on my laptop, and on a Redhat server. However, on my Mac Pro I am getting the following on both apps:

```
Passenger encountered the following error:
The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.
```

Nginx log file shows a segmentation fault:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:708: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10.4.0], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2011.01
```

I KNOW this has to be some gem issue. Unfortunately Passenger is not reporting it, and I have it's log level set to 3.

I have seen a few logging issues in Passenger that have caused me some headaches. I'm not complaining, it's free and it's fast. But I don't know how to get past this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backing off to Passenger 2.2.15 fixed my problem. Note that this error only occurs on Mac OS X 10.6.4 on my Mac Pro dual quad core CPU machine, NOT on my MacBook Pro laptop running the same version of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some kind of Ruby bug to me. Try 1.9? It looks like the Ruby core developers give 1.9 more attention than 1.8 these days.

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem with Ruby Enterprise (ree) 1.8.7-2011.02 and install Passenger that bundle with it.

Server is OpenSuSe 11.x 
Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7-2011.02
Passenger 3.0.2

/var/log/apache2/error_log show looks like this

```
*** glibc detected *** Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /srv/www/apps/xxxxxx/current: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000ccd400 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x73226)[0x7f40d5d1e226]
/lib64/libnsl.so.1(+0xfd4a)[0x7f40d40f3d4a]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(pthread_once+0x53)[0x7f40d5a9a943]
/lib64/libnsl.so.1(_nsl_default_nss+0x21)[0x7f40d40f3e61]
/lib64/libnss_compat.so.2(_nss_compat_initgroups_dyn+0x594)[0x7f40d4301de4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x9cc1b)[0x7f40d5d47c1b]
/lib64/libc.so.6(initgroups+0x6c)[0x7f40d5d47e7c]
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/ext/phusion_passenger/native_support.so(+0xf48)[0x7f40d4b5af48]
```

so, solution is install Passenger gem to your MRI Ruby.

```
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Last report of passenger should give you apache's configuration to MRI ruby /usr/bin/ruby

It is slower but till new patch is out, this is only solution for me.

Comment: Thanks Jirapong. What version of MRI are you running?

Comment: I use build-in OSX version. ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0], linux i use this - http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/12/25/ruby-1-8-7-p330-released/

Comment: more to try, but i'm not yet try with myself the REE today released at http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/02/24/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2011-03-released/

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error (on ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.5.0],
passenger 3.0.2, Mac OS X 10.6.6 dual Quad-Core) and reverting to Passenger 2.2.15 also worked for me. Weird! Thank you.